# React Native combine BottomTab with TopTab

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm trying to add top bar to my app, I already have a bottom tab working but I found it complicated adding the top tab with the bottom tab.. Here's my code:

```
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation  } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator >
    <Tab.Screen name="Post Room" component={PostANewRoomScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Rooms" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}

export const SecondComponent = ()  => {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <TopTab.Navigator>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </TopTab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}

export default App;
```

I think it might be a problem with the export when I change it to SecondComponent It only shows the top bar, I tried doing `export default (App,SecondComponent)` but it also showed an error

Comment: So do you want to nest one navigator inside the other ? whats the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I'm not getting any it just that the top bar doesn't appear only the bottom one

Comment: So you want to have top bar as the parent to bottom bar ?

Comment: yea like nesting them together so they both will appear

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you should do something like below

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const BottomNavigator = () => {
return (
  <Tab.Navigator >
    <Tab.Screen name="Post Room" component={PostANewRoomScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Rooms" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
 );
}

export const App = ()  => {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <TopTab.Navigator>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Bottom" component={BottomNavigator} />
  </TopTab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}

export default App;
```

By this the BottomNavigator which holds the bottom tabs would be nested inside the other one. and also stick to one navigation container.